# What gonna happen if you set an outdated 'Date' in Lifecycle Rule AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Currently, I am working on a project which has an s3 compliant server and I don't know how to handle the following condition.

Assume I have one object `aws/test.txt` and I want to delete it on a specific date which is before today. Today is `22 June 2022`, the midnight UTC time is `2022-06-22T00:00:00+00:00`, what gonna happen if I set an outdated date like `2022-06-21T00:00:00+00:00` to the lifecycle rule? Will s3 delete the object right now or do nothing?

Here is an example lifecycle JSON file:

```json
{
    "Rules": [
        {
            "Expiration": {
                "Date": "2022-06-21T00:00:00+00:00"
            },
            "ID": "rule-1",
            "Filter": {
                "Prefix": "aws/"
            },
            "Status": "Enabled"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: AWS will evaluate the expiration rules once in a day. - When and if outadated date is encontered, object will be deleted. -- check -- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-object-expiration/

Comment: An outdated date is never encountered, so the object `aws/test.txt` will be there all the time?

Comment: If Expiration Date < Present Date .. Delete Object.. This check happens once evryday.. Doesnt matter if put outdated date today.. Also ur query "I want to delete it on a specific date which is before today." this doesnt make sense. u can set specific date for future.. since you are setting past date as expiry date.. object will delete in next cycle of check..

Comment: `If Expiration Date < Present Date .. Delete Object.. ` I don't find the statement on [this page](aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-object-expiration), could you show me where you find it?

Comment: `If Expiration Date < Present Date .. Delete Object..` this argument is true. I just found `If you specify an S3 Lifecycle action with a date that is in the past, all qualified objects become immediately eligible for that Lifecycle action.` in the official document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/intro-lifecycle-rules.html#intro-lifecycle-rules-filter